# Using max-age and s-maxage together

Tags: symfony, caching, proxy

I have a symfony app working with [foshttpcachebundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSHttpCacheBundle) for caching.

I use cloudfare as proxy cache, [http cache](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html) for reverse proxy cache and I want to define different times for private cache (Browsers), for shared cache (cloudfare) and for proxy cache (http symfony cache). I follow this schema:

[image]

My configuration files is :

```
fos_http_cache:
    cache_control:
        defaults:
            overwrite: false
               match:
                   attributes:
                       _route: "api_news_article_cget_version"
                headers:
                   reverse_proxy_ttl: 120
                   cache_control:
                       public: true
                       max_age: 30
                       s_maxage: 60
                   last_modified: "30 seconds"
```

So, this configuration adds this header to the response

> Age:0 
>   Cache-Control:max-age=30, public, s-maxage=60
>   CF-RAY:3e6474b0b6590c17-AMS Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip 
>   Content-Type:application/json 
>   Date:Thu, 01 Feb 2018 11:08:58 GMT Last-Modified:Thu, 01 Feb 2018 11:09:28 GMT 
>   Server:cloudflare
>   Last-Modified:Thu, 01 Feb 2018 14:37:09 GMT

So, I am going to explain what I suppose:

- If I am the first user making a request I am going to get a 200 response with a fresh content ( it is right).
- If I update the content on the original server and then I keep making a request for 29 seconds my request is going to be 304 not modified ( because the content is cached in Cloudflare). ( This is right)
- After 30 seconds ( max-age), the next response I think that should be a 200 response. I suppose that because the browser needs to refresh the cache ( max-age = 30 seconds) but the response is going to be the same because the proxy cache is 60 seconds. This is not right, the browser keeps making requests in the same way and getting 304 code ( not modify ).
- After 60 seconds (s-maxage), I should get the fresh response with a code response of 200. This is true. But if I don't update the content in the original server I also get a status code of 200. I don't undestand why, I think that I should get a 304 response.

And now my questions:

- Why my browser is not getting a fresh response after 30 seconds? If I disable cache on google chrome I get a fresh response (status code = 200) in each request.
- Why is cache refreshed only when the s_maxage ends?
- How can I do to get a different cache time in the browser and in Proxy cache?